# right position an element that has already been left positioned

Tags: html, css

I have css class which sets a span to a particular left position.

```
left: 0.5em;
```

How do I override that left value to:

```
right: 0.5em;
```

...either inline or in another class?

in other words, how do you set the left value to nothing or null?

Comment: I'm unsure what you're asking but if you're wondering how you'd override CSS you simply do the new styling inline and keep the original in an external file or at the top of the file.

Comment: I've given an answer, but I'm unsure what you mean about overriding `left` to `right`. They are two separate properties. An element can have **both** `left` and `right` set.

Comment: @thirtydot - your answer was bang on. I wanted to set the left value to an empty value as if it hadn't been set. I was forgetting that auto is the default value and that would do the same. thanks

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Perhaps the answer is `left: auto`?

[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/3dnSQ/1/)

Comment: You might be right. Just a quick note, the position will not change in the fiddle because you haven't set a `position` (ex absolute).

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to approach this.  If you just have one element you want to override, you can include different styling within that element.  If you want to modify the CSS rule itself, the best approach is to use Javascript.  All the CSS rules are stored in an array - `document.styleSheets[i].cssRules`.  You can iterate over this and then update the appropriate rule as needed.

This blog post also has a nice tutorial that you might want to review:
[Updating CSS with Javascript](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Totally_Pwn_CSS_with_Javascript)